# FFmpeg conversion to Photo-JPEG is blocky

Tags: ffmpeg

I am converting .mp4 files to .mov with the Photo-JPEG codec to use in After Effects to reduce render times.

I have looked up the FFmpeg commands to do this and come up with:

```
ffmpeg -i tower-bridge.mp4 -an -pix_fmt yuvj420p -vcodec mjpeg -f mov -y tower-bridge.mov
```

This works but when I look at the output video it is quite blocky; like a mosaic.

During the conversion I get this message:

```
[swscaler @ 0000000008c97fe0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
```

Research on-line suggests I can ignore this message.

What can I do to improve the output quality?
MediaInfo report on Input file:

Complete name : F:\london-tower-bridge.mp4
Format : MPEG-4
Format profile : Base Media
Codec ID : isom (isom/avc1/mp42)
File size : 18.7 MiB
Duration : 13 s 625 ms
Overall bit rate : 11.5 Mb/s

ID : 1
Format: AVC
Format/Info : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile : Baseline@L4
Format settings, CABAC : No
Format settings, ReFrames : 3 frames
Codec ID : avc1
Codec ID/Info : Advanced Video Coding
Duration : 13 s 625 ms
Bit rate : 11.5 Mb/s
Maximum bit rate : 26.8 Mb/s
Width : 1 920 pixels
Height : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio : 16:9
Frame rate mode : Constant
Frame rate : 24.000 FPS
Color space : YUV
Chroma subsampling : 4:2:0
Bit depth : 8 bits
Scan type : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame) : 0.231
Stream size : 18.7 MiB (100%)
Writing library : Zencoder Video Encoding System

MediaInfo report on Output file:

Complete name : F:\london-tower-bridge.mov
Format : MPEG-4
Format profile : QuickTime
Codec ID : qt   0000.02 (qt  )
File size : 16.1 MiB
Duration : 13 s 625 ms
Overall bit rate mode : Variable
Overall bit rate : 9 912 kb/s
Writing application : Lavf57.72.101

ID : 1
Format : JPEG
Codec ID : jpeg
Duration : 13 s 625 ms
Bit rate mode : Variable
Bit rate : 9 910 kb/s
Width : 1 920 pixels
Height : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio : 16:9
Frame rate mode : Constant
Frame rate : 24.000 FPS
Color space : YUV
Chroma subsampling : 4:2:0
Bit depth : 8 bits
Scan type : Progressive
Compression mode : Lossy
Bits/(Pixel*Frame) : 0.199
Stream size : 16.1 MiB (100%)
Language : English

Comment: I avoid using MJPEG, or any other lossy format, for intermediate files due to the generational quality loss. When not using the original file I'll use a lossless format such as [UT Video](http://umezawa.dyndns.info/archive/utvideo/?C=M;O=D).

Comment: Tried UT Video.  Works better.  I didn't know Photo-JPEG and MJPEG were the same thing; hence the duplication.